# Angular JS authInterceptor Service console error

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build authentication for my app. However I came across an error that appeared in the chrome window console, not sure what the problem is. Please see below code /error.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

```
   ##authInterceptorService.js##

 (function ()
{
   var injectParams = ['$rootScope', 'authService'];

    function authInterceptorFactory($rootScope, authService)
    {
    factory = {};

    factory.request = function(config)
    {
        var currentUser = authService.getCurrentUser(),
            access_token = currentUser ? currentUser.access_token : null;

        if(access_token)
        {
            config.headers.authorization = access_token;
        }

        return config;
    };

    factory.responseError = function(response)
    {
        if(response.status === 401)
        {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
        }

        return response;
    };

    return factory;
};

authInterceptorFactory.$inject = injectParams;

angular
    .module('rdApp.authModule')
    .factory('authInterceptorService', authInterceptorFactory);
 }());



    ##authService.js##
(function()
{
var injectParams = ['$http', 'store'];

function authFactory($http, store)
{
    factory = {};
    var urlBase = '-------';
    var currentUser = null;

    factory.setCurrentUser = function(user)
    {
        currentUser = user;
        store.set('user', user);

        return currentUser;
    };

    factory.getCurrentUser = function()
    {
        if(!currentUser)
        {
            currentUser = store.get('user');
        }

        return currentUser;
    };

    factory.signIn = function (user)
    {
        return $http.post(urlBase + '-----', user);
    };

    return factory;
};

authFactory.$inject = injectParams;

angular
    .module('rdApp.authModule')
    .factory('authService', authFactory);

}());


/*CONSOLE ERROR */
TypeError: authService.getCurrentUser is not a function
at factory.request (authInterceptorService.js:11)
at angular.min.js:119
at m.$eval (angular.min.js:134)
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:131)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:134)
at angular.min.js:19
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:38)
at d (angular.min.js:19)
at yc (angular.min.js:20)
at Xd (angular.min.js:18)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
```

Comment: Help would be really appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: I can't reproduce the error at plunkr so pls give me one but bro nice coding pattern its very clear

Comment: Hey @vengicx i got it working, it was a strange issue. But i ended up re building the authentication a bit more robust. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ErkanDemir I am experiencing similar error. Was your error something like this `Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 setRequestHeader@[native code]` or `Error: [$compile:tpload]` ?